# Can't INSERT INTO postgres column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with the following schema:

```
           Column           |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |                Default                 | Storage  | Stats target | Description
----------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+----------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id                         | integer                     |           | not null | nextval('test_table_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              |
 orig_filename              | text                        |           | not null |                                        | extended |              |
 file_extension             | text                        |           | not null |                                        | extended |              |
 created_date               | date                        |           | not null |                                        | plain    |              |
 last_modified_date         | date                        |           | not null |                                        | plain    |              |
 upload_timestamp_utc       | timestamp without time zone |           | not null |                                        | plain    |              |
 uploaded_by                | text                        |           | not null |                                        | extended |              |
 file_size_in_bytes         | integer                     |           | not null |                                        | plain    |              |
 original_containing_folder | text                        |           | not null |                                        | extended |              |
 file_data                  | bytea                       |           | not null |                                        | extended |              |
 source_shortname           | text                        |           |          |                                        | extended |              |
Indexes:
    "test_table_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

I appended the source_shortname column after building the table.  I now want to INSERT values into the columns.

When I run this command:

```
INSERT INTO test_table(source_shortname) VALUES('name');
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR:  null value in column "orig_filename" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (31, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, name).
```

I didn't set the source_shortname column to "not null" so I'm not sure why it's throwing that error.  Particularly because there are only 28 rows and this seems to throw an error on row 31.

Comment: As your table definition clearly shows you certainly did create that table with a `not null` constraint for `orig_filename`

Comment: Based on your schema all of your columns up until and including `file_data` are not nullable which means you have to provide a value on insert. I do find it a little ironic that the one column you are providing a value for *is* nullable (would allow for a null value).

Comment: Maybe you got your DDL script wrong and inverted the value or meaning of the value for nullable?

Answer (score 0):

You are inserting entire records at a time, so when you insert and specify only one value for one column, it will implicitly assume that all the rest will be NULL. You need to insert a complete record and not have any NULL values in the insert statement.

```
INSERT INTO test_table( 
 orig_filename             
 ,file_extension             
 ,created_date               
 ,last_modified_date         
 ,upload_timestamp_utc       
 ,uploaded_by                
 ,file_size_in_bytes         
 ,original_containing_folder 
 ,file_data                  
 ,source_shortname)
VALUES 
('','','','','','','','','','name')
```

Or you need to run an update instead since you just added that column and you want to insert something into that column

```
UPDATE test_table 
SET source_shortname = 'name'
WHERE source_shortname IS NULL
```

Comment: Yes, just ..  not all column data types are textual

Comment: @OtoShavadze Then take a couple seconds, pick some default values, and use those as placeholders?